# How to determine if Mysql update succeeded

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to determine if Mysql update succeeded with PDO PHP?

Check affected rows

```
$sth->rowCount();
```

This would only work if the updated row has changes, but what if the row is unchanged?? Then `$sth->rowCount()` would return `0` even if the update has succeeded...

Comment: If the number is zero (or less then you excepted) wouldn't that you tell rows were unaffected?

Comment: You can make PDO throw exceptions on error and catch them.

Comment: define "succeeded". And why do you think it may not succeed? Or, in other words - why do you need it for update only?

Comment: I could both need it for update and delete.. So I don't need to request a select count query before update and delete

Answer (score -1):

The normal way to do this would be to construct a COUNT query on the same criteria, and run it before your UPDATE.

This could be subject to race conditions depending whether you're running in a transaction, and if so on the isolation level. So the real answer depends what you need the number for.

Comment: this should be part of comment instead of answer

Comment: This is actually *abnormal* way. Mind race conditions.

Comment: Nonsense, the OP wants to know how many rows matched his UPDATE, and isolating a COUNT in the same transaction is, to the best of my knowledge, the *only* way to achieve that. I'll look forward to seeing anyone else come up with a better answer.